# Is the function $f$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $m$ is the Lebesgue measure and $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable with $ 0\neq m(A)<\infty$. Define $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $ f(x)= m((-\infty,x]\cap A)$. Does it follow that $f$ is continuous on $ A $ or $ A^c$?

Comment: "Is function continuous?" Well, you forgot about measure in your definition of $f$, don't you?

Comment: @sas Huh? $\quad$

Comment: Yeah, now it contains $f(x)=m(\cdots$. The letter $m$ wasn't there before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume $y>x$. Then
$$
\left|f(y)-f(x)\right| =
\big|m((-\infty,y]\cap A) -m((-\infty,x]\cap A)\big| =
\big|m((x,y]\cap A)\big|\le
\left|y-x\right|
$$
So $f$ is (even Lipshitz) continuous.

Comment: oh, and it does not matter whether on $A$ or it's complement, since it is continous on $\mathbb{R}$, and hence on each subset.

Comment: Dose it is Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: What should be Lebesgue integrable? $f$? It is continous and has bounded integral (which is true), it is for sure.

Comment: @Tomas yes. $ f $

Comment: So $ f $ is Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: @nim Yes. $f$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Dose $ f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $ \mathbb{R} $?

Comment: @nim $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f|= m(A) < \infty$ by assumption, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

Show that it is continuous on $A$. If $x_n\nearrow x$ increasingly, then we should show that
$$f(x_n)\to f(x) \text{ as } n\to\infty.$$
We have
$$f(x_n)=m((-\infty,x_n]\cap A)\to m((-\infty,x]\cap A)=f(x),$$
using the continuity of Lebesgue measure and
$$\left( (-\infty,x_n]\cap A\right)\subset ((-\infty,x_{n+1}]\cap A),\quad n\ge 1.$$

In the same way can be seen the case $x_n\searrow x.$