# Showing a measurable function is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, uniform-continuity, measurable-functions

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set with $m(E) < \infty$. Define the functoin $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$f(x) = m(E \cap (-\infty,x])$.

Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Here is my attempt at a proof, but I am not confident in it.
We want to show $\forall x,y$ and $\epsilon > 0$ $\exists \delta > 0$ such that if $|x - y| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$

Let $\delta = \epsilon$

Then,
$|x - y| < \delta$

$|m(E \cap (-\infty,x]) - m(E \cap (-\infty,y]|$

$= |m(E \cap ((-\infty,x] - (\infty,y]))|$

$\leq |m((-\infty,x] - (-\infty,y])|$

$= |m(-\infty + \infty,x - y])|$

Now, here is the step I'm quite unsure of (in fact I think it is wrong). Since this is simply our function evaluated at two different points, I think it's possible that the two infinities are the same level of infinity. So in that case, wouldn't $\infty - \infty = 0$?

$=|m(0,x - y)|$

$= |x - y - 0| = |x - y| < \delta = \epsilon$

I have two issues with my proof, but I can't seem to think of a different way to proceed. One I already mentioned (the infinity issue), and the other is that I don't see how my proof is any different than one for normal continuity. I know somewhere in here there needs to be an emphasis on why the function is uniformly continuous, but I don't see how I could include that. Can anyone shine some light on this? Thanks!

Comment: If $x\leq y$, then $m(E\cap (-\infty,y])-m(E\cap (-\infty,x])=m(E\cap (x,y)) \leq m((x,y))= y-x$. So, $f$ is even Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant $1$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1731287/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/704270/42969 for correct proofs.

Comment: @MartinR the links you sent me are for continuous functions. I need uniform continuity proved here.

Comment: @peek-a-boo why is the step $m(E \cap (-\infty,y]) - m(E \cap (-\infty,x]) = m(E \cap (x,y))$ true? I don't recall a theorem showing that, and I thought it yielded what I had above. And also, what about the uniform continuity part?

Comment: If $A\subset B$ are measurable sets with finite measure, what is $m(B)-m(A)$? Also, it seems like you're confusing the set difference symbol with subtraction. Lastly, I showed you that your function is Lipschitz continuous. It is a standard exercise, using just basic definitions, that Lipschitz continuity implies uniform continuity, hence also continuity.

Comment: @DominicBlanco: Look at those proofs. They show that $|f (x)-f (y)|\leq |x-y|$, which implies uniform continuity.

Comment: @peek-a-boo $m(B) - m(A) \leq m(B - A)$ that is an inequality I have proved. It is quite possible I am mixing up definitions. I never took set theory (because my university doesn't have a class in it), and many of my peers at the same university also feel they are weak in set theory. Does it behave differently here?

Comment: @MartinR I will take a look and see.

Comment: @DominicBlanco Then you're missing out on a basic fact about measure theory. $m(B)-m(A)=m(B\setminus A)$, where $B\setminus A=\{x\,:\,\text{$x\in B$ and $x\notin A$}\}$, i.e those elements of $B$ which do not lie in $A$ (google this if it's unclear, there are surely nice helpful pictures illustrating set differences). And please don't use $B-A$, because very often in measure theory that notation is used for a different set, namely $B-A=\{b-a\,:\, b\in B\,\,a\in A\}$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo alright, I'll take a look. Thank you for the tips! I believe I have enough of a hint from this. So would you like to post your hint as an answer and I can accept it? Or should I just delete the question?

Comment: how about write up your own answer to see if you've understood it properly :)

Comment: @peek-a-boo sure I can do that! Let me give it a shot. I'll take a look at some of the set theory before I do so.

Comment: @peek-a-boo so to confirm my understanding, I'm trying to do another example. I'm trying to do $f(x) = m(E \cap [-x,x])$. I'm proceeding the same way, and if $x > y$, I think I would get $m(E \cap [-x,x]) - m(E \cap [-y,y]) = m(E \cap [-x - y,x + y]) \leq m([-x-y,x + y]) = x + y - (-x - y) = x + y + x + y = 2x + 2y = 2(x + y)$. But this is a problem! I can't relate this to $\delta$ because $|x - y| < \delta$. It isn't Lipschitz either. Am I missing something on the arithmetic here?

Comment: You're messing up the basic set theory: $[-x,x]\setminus [-y,y]$ is not $[-x-y,x+y]$. Draw a picture of the interval $[-y,y]$. Draw a picture of $[-x,x]$. What is the leftover portion?

Comment: I just drew it, and I believe it is $[y - x,x - y]$. If $x > y$, then we have "space" for say from $y$ to $x$ on the right, which I think would be $x - y$. The other "space" is from $-y$ to $-x$ on the left, which I think would be $-x - (-y) = y - x$. If that's true, I would have $x - y - (y - x) = x - y - y + x = 2x - 2y = 2(x - y) = 2\delta$. That works! Is that on the right track?

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set with $m(E) < \infty$. Define the functoin $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by
> $f(x) = m(E \cap (-\infty,x])$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

**Proof**:
We need to show that, for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is  $\delta > 0$ such that, for all $x,y \in \Bbb R$,  if $|x - y| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. (Note that the choice of $\delta$ must not depend on $x$ or $y$).

Given any $\epsilon > 0$, let $\delta = \epsilon$.  Then, for any  $x,y \in \Bbb R$, we can assume without loss of generality that $x\leqslant y$, and so $m(E \cap (-\infty,x]) \leqslant m(E \cap (-\infty,y])$. So,  we have that, if  $|x - y| < \delta$, then
\begin{align*}
|f(x) - f(y)| &= | m(E \cap (-\infty,x]) - m(E \cap (-\infty,y])|= \\
&= m(E \cap (-\infty,y]) - m(E \cap (-\infty,x]) = \\
&= m((E \cap (-\infty,y]) \setminus (E \cap (-\infty,x])) =\\
&= m (E \cap (( -\infty,y] \setminus (-\infty,x])) = \\
&= m(E \cap (x,y]) \leqslant \\
& \leqslant m((x,y]) = y-x = |x-y| <\delta = \epsilon
\end{align*}
(see **Remark 1** for details).

So, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. $\square$

**Remark 1**:

1. We used in the proof above that if $A \subseteq B$ and $m(A)< \infty$, then $m(B) - m(A) = m(B \setminus A)$, where $B \setminus A$ is the set difference of $B$ and $A$, that is, $B \setminus A = \{p: p\in B \textrm{ and } p\notin A\} $.
2. We also used, assuming $x \leqslant y$, that $ ( -\infty,y] \setminus (-\infty,x] = (x, y]$. Let us prove it.

We have
\begin{align*}
( -\infty,y] \setminus (-\infty,x] & = \{ p \in \Bbb R : p \leqslant y \} \setminus \{ p \in \Bbb R : p \leqslant x \} = \\
& =  \{ p \in \Bbb R : p \leqslant y \textrm { and not }( p \leqslant x )\} = \\
& =  \{ p \in \Bbb R : p \leqslant y \textrm { and } p > x \} = \\
& = (x, y]
\end{align*}

**Remark 2**: We actually proved more. We proved that, for all $x, y \in \Bbb R$, $|f(x) - f(y)| \leqslant |x-y|$. So, $f$ is a Lipschitz continuous function.

Comment: Hi, @Ramiro this is great! This is exactly what I had down from earlier. I was wondering, could you possibly look at the question I asked in the comments as well? It was posted in the above comments. I was trying to look at an example of $f(x) = m(E \cap [-x,x])$ to make sure I understand the set theory. Was my last comment correct in that it becomes $m([y - x,x - y])$? Thank you for this answer though!

Comment: @DominicBlanco Regarding the question in the comments, if $x>y$ ,  $[-x,x] \setminus [-y,y] = [-x, -y) \cup (y, x]$ . It is not an interval, but the union of two disjoint intervals. Then we have: 
$$ m([-x, -y) \cup (y, x])= m([-x, -y) )+ m( (y, x]) =  (x-y) +(x-y) = 2(x-y)= 2\delta$$

However, although $m ([y-x, x-y])$ is also $2(x-y)$, it is **not** true that $[-x, -y) \cup (y, x] = [y-x, x-y]$.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. That clears up a lot of my confusion. Thank you for clarifying that! I think I understand the set theory better now.